# Bash command to find files that match file[0-9]+.js

Tags: bash

I'm trying to work out how I can **match** files app1.js, app2.js, but **NOT** app-foo-1.js in a directory. Currently I have this in my bash script:

```
for d in /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/app*.js ; do
    filename="${d##*/}"
    echo "$d"
    echo "$filename"

    echo " "
done
```

This matches them - but it also matches app-whatever.js

How can I trim this down to just the ones I want? I'm sure its simple but I'm just grabbing code from tutorials online as I'm not a bash programmer =)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are looking for extglob, it is equivalent to regular expressions, not as convenient as ERE or expressive as PCRE but allows to do the job

```
shopt -s extglob

for d in file+([0-9]).js ; do

...
```

where `file` has to be changed with appropriate pattern, was taken from title.

from [Pattern matching in Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

> If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a ‘|’. Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ?(pattern-list)
>
> ```
> Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
> ```
>
> *(pattern-list)
>
> ```
> Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
> ```
>
> +(pattern-list)
>
> ```
> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.
> ```
>
> @(pattern-list)
>
> ```
> Matches one of the given patterns.
> ```
>
> !(pattern-list)
>
> ```
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns.
> ```

Comment: thanks - this seems to do the trick : `for d in /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/app+([0-9]).js ; do`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command to search for files according to your desired pattern and execute a command on each result using the `-exec` parameter:

```
find /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/ \
    -type f \
    -regex '.*app[0-9]+.js' \
    -exec ls -la {} \;
```

The command from above would execute `ls -la` on every matching search result.

Comment: thanks for that. I did look into find, but I wasn't sure how I then run my commands through it?

Answer (score 0):

`for d in app[0-9].js; do echo $d; done`

or addressing the issue with multiple digits:

```
find $path -regextype egrep -regex '.*/app[0-9]+.js'
```

You can pass commands using `-exec`:

```
find $path -regextype egrep -regex '.*/app[0-9]+.js' -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: The OP would expect to match with `app10.js` as well because the header line indicates `file[0-9]+.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As someone else commented, that doesn't seem to work with app30.js (or anything past 9)

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

`find /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js -iregex '.*\/app[0-9]*\.js'`

A complete example:

```
cd /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js
for file in $(find . -iregex '.*\/app[0-9]*\.js')
do
  echo $file
done
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22092727)

Comment: @Bsquare: whats the problem with it?

Comment: same as your other (flagged) answer: lack of explanation input/output sample. Flesh your answer

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it with grep, which allows to match one or more numbers:

`find /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/ -type f | grep "app[0-9]\+"`

and if you have to execute a command with these files:

```
for file in $(find /home/chambres/web/x.org/public_html/2018/js/ -type f | grep "app[0-9]\+"); do
echo $file;
done;
```

Comment: see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54478819/1454708) without find and grep

Comment: That's possibly the worst thing you could do: it will miserably fail if there are filenames with spaces or glob characters. Moreover, piping `find` and `grep` is a total antipattern! (`find` has the name-based filter `-name`, and your `grep` will not work on basenames but on the full path). Please remove or fix this answer, so that we stop spreading bad shell practices!

Comment: fair point, but how to you do you match more than one digit with `-name`?  You can also write a pattern to match the end of the path...

Comment: Use `-regex` option. You will need to specify `-regextype` option along with it.